# Imputing missing values for linear regression model, using linear regression

Tags: linear-regression, missing-data, imputation, data-wrangling

I scraped a real estate website and would like to impute missing data on total area (about 40% missing) using linear regression. I achieve the best results using price, number of rooms, bedrooms, bathrooms, and powder rooms.

[Correlation matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aga2B.png)

Adding price to the room information makes a significant difference. This makes sense, since the number of rooms alone don't give you any information on how large those rooms may be. Price can reduce some of that uncertainty. There is a 20 point difference between the R^2 scores of the model that includes and the one that excludes price (0.62 vs 0.82).

The problem that I see, is that my final model would likely also be a liner regression with price as the target. With this, it seems wrong to include price in predicting total area for imputation. My final model will look better as a consequence but I will have engineered a synthetic correlation. This is especially critical since about 40% of values need to be replaced.

Does anyone disagree with this? Should I keep price as a predictor to impute missing values even though it will be the target of my final model?

Comment: I think you may need to ask this in https://stats.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I will also post it there.

Answer (score 0):

Based by context, I think you're talking about Hotel prices?

Based from my experience, imputing missing values for your predictor values, it can really make a significant boost to R^2 Scores, however the more you impute the predictor, the fewer observations you have, and thus it will be bias to conclude that to a bigger picture of Hotel Prices, since you may never know if there exist unobserved Hotel Prices with more variation right?

Comment: Yea, it's real estate prices so in essence the same thing. What about the fact that I am using the target as 1 out of 6 predictors for predicting imputing values? Do you see that as a problem or not?

Comment: Linear Regression accuracy can be vary depending of your predictors and observation, if 1 out of 6 predictors can give you a good predction model , then I think its not a problem at all, it simply means that predictor is good enough to predict the Prices

Comment: 1 more thing, if your response values have a lot of missing values, I think linear regression will not be suitable since it needed non missing values, in this case you can use what is called tobit regression, since it allows for missing values when modeling by censoring some values

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I haven't heard of tobit regression yet. However, I think I may not have explained the situation clearly.

What I am trying to do is perform a multiple linear regression to predict housing prices. One of my features, total area in sqft, has about 40% missing values. However, the non missing values correlate very well with the target, price, which is why I would like to keep.

Comment: I think thats good to go, wether its correlate or not, what is the problem of that?

Comment: I'm using the target to predict a feature and then use that feature to predict the target again. That's circular and seems problematic to me but I could be wrong.

Comment: That's a simplified version of the actual situation. In reality price is only 1 out of 5 predictors and the imputed feature is only one out of several predictors for the final model.